# Can't remove box shadow on visited link - applied twice

Tags: css, box-shadow

Not sure if this is just related to `:visited` links or a general styling thing with box-shadow, but I can't get it to override.

https://jsfiddle.net/pt39v1yy/1/

I was initially trying to change the color of the box-shadow, but then realized it was not overriding the thing so I tried to remove as well and still nothing. I tried adding !important, unset, initial, etc but inspecting always shows the original box-shadow is not crossed out, it's like it can't be overridden.

```
a:not(.btn) {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b4e7f8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #b4e7f8;
    -webkit-transition: background .35s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
    transition: background .35s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
    color: inherit;
}
a:not(.btn):hover{
    background: #b4e7f8;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 a:not(.btn):visited {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #beb4f8;
  background: #beb4f8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Helloo,

According to MDN: You can only apply certain properties to the `:visited` selector in CSS, and box-shadow is not one of them.

> **Note:** For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited rule is used).

For more information on the current limitations take a look at: [Privacy and the :visited selector.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

Maybe you could do something like this if you really want to have the `box-shadow`: https://jsfiddle.net/pt39v1yy/2/

I hope this helps!